# SQL Server 2016 integration with R Services

Tags: r, sql-server-2016

While trying to integrate R Studio with SQL Server 2016 I am getting following error:

> Unable to launch runtime for 'R' script. Please check the configuration of the 'R' runtime.

As suggested on different sites it is advised to install `"%programfiles%\RRO\RRO-3.2.2-for-RRE-7.5.0\R-3.2.2\library\RevoScaleR\rxLibs\x64\RegisterRExt.exe" /install`.

But I have already installed R studio and not able to find the path specified.

Comment: RStudio is an application for editing R code (like SQL Server Management Studio is an application for editing SQL Server Code). R is a programming language - presumably you have it installed? RevoScaleR is another version of the R programming language, and is different from R (and very different from RStudio which is just an editor/IDE). To use R with SQL Server, I think RevoScaleR is required.

Answer (score 2):

R Services for SQL 2016 is a new offering from Microsoft - who purchased Revolution Analytics about a year ago. This is the first major result of that.

SQL Server 2016  is in (CTP - community technical preview), so not really finished (although you can download and use a version that will expire after about 6 months). Also a lot of the docs are incomplete and there are probably a fair amount of bugs. However it has been long announced that it will include "R Services for SQL 2016", which is based on the Revolution R Engine. In order to use that you have to

1. Install SQL Server 2016 CTP as usual.
2. Install the "Advanced Analytics Extensions" from the **setup.exe** program (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt590808.aspx)
3. Obtain the appropriate RevoScaleR packages (there are two) and install them, one your client, and one on the machine running SQL 2016. They are described here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt604883.aspx
4. Then to test it you can follow the instructions here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt590808.aspx

Good luck with it, but remember it is still in pre-release development and testing, so problems are to be expected.

Comment: Is the SQL Server 2016 <--> R integration possible *without* having to get the commercial version of Revolution R Enterprise?

Comment: Yes. SQL Server 2016 will essentially enable the writing of stored procedures in R.

Comment: thanks. have a follow up question - so am I right thiking that with this `SQL-R` integration I would be able to store data in `SQL`, run `R` code inside to compute new columns etc. _and_ fit statistical models to it - ideally `collect()`-ing only the models back into main memory at the end?

Comment: Yes, you are right to think that. Although the details of just what is in memory when is obviously rather complicated when talking about SQL and RevoR together.